# How to convert Mac to string?

Tags: java

How do I convert the MAC data type to String? I am able to use base64 to encode the SecretKey data type into a String but this doesn't work for MAC.

```
// Generate a secret MAC key

KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HmacSHA1");  
SecretKey key = kg.generateKey();
String encodedkey=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key.getEncoded());


// Create and initialize a MAC with the key
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
mac.init(key);

// Print the key

System.out.println("Key:" + encodedkey);

// Print out the resulting MAC

System.out.println("MAC:" + mac);
```

My output

```
Key:lnGahJHeKDqMG+c/K8OHx9HiQQl+aqhCNb0QtnDAdhzE3Xs7gP0uXf93ESO9Demrnl0XFCqHVUBsU9oppkmgVQ==
MAC:javax.crypto.Mac@1ce92674
```

Desired sample output

```
Key: lqC5SNoKYPnQRVFxTp2YhvBQpWiZU7sWTjziVXgMmcFkxvBJQA81PoTqrvscOyj05pvm6MBtlvP6gkqJvisiNQ==
MAC: xca73kbvEEZBKwb0aWMhGA==
```

Answer (score 27):

The `Mac` class itself isn't the data - it holds the data and updates it on calls to `update` and `doFinal`.

Currently you're only calling `init` with the key - you then need to call `update` (optionally) and then `doFinal`. When you call `doFinal`, that will return a `byte[]` of the actual hash. Currently we can't see any data that you want to hash, but your sample would be changed like this:

```
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
mac.init(key);
mac.update(data1);
mac.update(data2);
mac.update(data3);
// Etc...
byte[] hash = mac.doFinal();
String base64Hash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);
```

You can also call `doFinal` passing in data - if you only have a single piece of data to hash, this means you don't need to call `update` at all:

```
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
mac.init(key);
byte[] hash = mac.doFinal(data);
String base64Hash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);
```

Answer (score -1):

HmacSHA1 is a hash so it means it works only one way, you cannot get the original value from it. You would need to use algorithm that is reversible.

Comment: I don't think the OP is trying to get an original value back - but they're not currently providing any data to hash.